# Python - Compressing collection of TO and FROM value ranges across rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that consists of the following.  For each group, you'll see repeated "ranges" that are represented in the form of a set of from/to columns (i.e. value_x_low to value_x_high).

For example, 40000 to 50000 is reflected as the 'from' and 'to' range for value_1, for GROUP1, for the first 3 records; whereas the 4th record has a 'from' and 'to' range of 60000 to 70000.  Continuing, within the 40000 to 50000 range established for value_1, 000 to ZZZ is repeated twice in the value_2 low/high fields, etc.

| group | value_1_low | value_1_high | value_2_low | value_2_high | value_3_low | value_3_high |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GROUP1 | 40000 | 50000 | 000 | ZZZ | 123 | 123 |
| GROUP1 | 40000 | 50000 | 000 | ZZZ | 456 | 456 |
| GROUP1 | 40000 | 50000 | ABC | ABC | 789 | 789 |
| GROUP1 | 60000 | 70000 | 000 | ZZZ | 000 | 999 |
| GROUP2 | 40000 | 50000 | 000 | ZZZ | 123 | 123 |
| GROUP2 | 40000 | 50000 | 000 | ZZZ | 456 | 456 |
| GROUP2 | 40000 | 50000 | 000 | ZZZ | 789 | 789 |
| GROUP2 | 40000 | 50000 | 000 | ZZZ | 012 | 012 |

Essentially, I'm attempting to compress the table above by removing repeating values as I traverse from value_1 to value_2 to value_3 etc...An output that would conform to expectations is below (where I've essentially constructed the potential sample output as a nested dict in which each range is represented as a tuple).

```
{'GROUP1': {(40000, 50000): {(000, ZZZ): [(123, 123), (456, 456)], ('ABC', 'ABC'): [(789, 789)]},
           {(60000, 70000): {(000, ZZZ): [(000, 999)]}},
 'GROUP2': {(40000, 50000): {(000, ZZZ): [(123, 123), (456, 456), (789, 789), (012, 012)]}}}
```

I've attempted to using a dict comprehension below; however, I'm struggling with layering in the additional "groupbys".

```
grouped_dict = {k: f.groupby(['value_1_low', 'value_1_high'])['value_2_low', 
                                                              'value_2_high', 
                                                              'value_3_low', 
                                                              'value_3_high'].apply(lambda g: g.value.tolist()).to_dict()
for k, f in group_dataframe.groupby('group')}
```

Also, I was wondering if there is a package already available that optimized this sort of compression.  Because in certain instances, initially grouping by value_1_low/value_1_high may NOT return the most compressed results.

This is my first post....so, let me know if I've complied with formatting/etc. requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it easier to manipulate the dictionary, first create the tuples that will be used as keys to the desired dictionary. Use `apply` with `axis=1` to access each row and get the low and high values for each `value_X` pair. Use `groupby(["g", "v1", "v2"])` to create the groups, leaving `v3` that will be used to create the tuples list.

Iterate over each created group and, for each group, use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) with the group name as parameter to it. The `setdefault` will return the value of that key if the key is in the dictionary, if not, the key is inserted with the value in the second parameter of the function. As a final step, you can then assign the `v3` column as `list` to the dictionary.

If you want to preserve the leading zeros in the output dictionary, like the tuples `[0, 999]`, `....(789, 789), (12, 12)]` that were originally `[000, 999]` and `012`, you would have to convert the data to a string (`astype(str)`).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", sep="\s+")
print(df)

do = pd.DataFrame()
do["g"] = df.group
do["v1"] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.value_1_low, x.value_1_high), axis=1)
do["v2"] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.value_2_low, x.value_2_high), axis=1)
do["v3"] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.value_3_low, x.value_3_high), axis=1)

df_group = do.groupby(["g", "v1", "v2"])

d_out = {}
for gn, gv in df_group:
    d1 = d_out.setdefault(gn[0], {gn[1]: {}})
    d2 = d1.setdefault(gn[1], {gn[2]: {}})
    d2[gn[2]] = gv.v3.to_list()

print(d_out)
```

Output from *d_out*

```py
{
    "GROUP1": {
        (40000, 50000): {
            ("000", "ZZZ"): [(123, 123), (456, 456)],
            ("ABC", "ABC"): [(789, 789)],
        },
        (60000, 70000): {("000", "ZZZ"): [(0, 999)]},
    },
    "GROUP2": {
        (40000, 50000): {("000", "ZZZ"): [(123, 123), (456, 456), (789, 789), (12, 12)]}
    },
}
```